# How to limit where a sprite can move in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I am fairly new to Unity so please bear with me I have tried looking for the answer everywhere, but have had no luck.

Basically I am using onMouseDrag to move a sprite around the background for a classroom (1366x768) that has a table. However, I want to limit where the sprite can go so that it does not end up off screen or off of the table on my background.

My sprite has the 2d box collider and rigidbody components attached (gravity is set to zero and it is at a fixed angle). I thought that by placing four 2d box colliders around the area I want to keep the sprite in it would be enough to contain it but the sprite simply goes straight through them.

I also read up about using Mathf.Clamp to restrict the area but I do not really understand how to use it from the examples I have seen.

Below is my code for moving the sprite:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MovementScript : MonoBehaviour {

    float x;
    float y;

    void Update() {
        x = Input.mousePosition.x;
        y = Input.mousePosition.y;
    }

    public void OnMouseDrag() {
        transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (x, y, 1.0f));
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving an object using its `transform` is not the same as moving it.

When you use the `transform`, the object doesn't "move", it teleports every `Update` by a small amount. Unfortunately, the `Rigidbody` can't detect this change in position as movement and thus does not react with any colliders. Regardless, that's probably the more complicated way to do this. Using `Clamp` is definitely easier.

[`Clamp`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) is a pretty straightforward function. it takes three args: a `value`, a `min`, and a `max`. If the value is less than `min` or greater than `max`, it returns that boundary. Otherwise, it returns the value itself.

For instance,

```
Mathf.Clamp(5, 1, 3); //returns 3
Mathf.Clamp(2, 1, 3); //returns 2
Mathf.Clamp(-2, 1, 3); //returns 1
```

This is simply a convenience function for something like this:

```
if(val > max) {
    return max;
} else if(val < min) {
    return min;
} else {
    return val;
}
```

So using `Clamp`, you can restrict the values of your `x` and `y` coordinates:

```
//to avoid confusion, I'm referring to your x and y variables
//as inputX and inputY. they represent the mouse position.
public void OnMouseDrag() {
    Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;
    pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(inputX, minX, maxX);
    pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(inputY, minY, maxY);
    pos.z = 1.0;
    transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (pos);
}
```

`Mathf.Clamp` will keep the X and Y coordinates of your Transform within the range (`minX`, `maxX`) and (`minY`, `maxY`) respectively. You can create these variables as inspector variables so you can change them on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I understand everything that you have said and tried to implement the code (I changed the inputX and inputY to x and y and I put values in for the minimum and maximum coordinates at the inspector). However, as soon as I click on the sprite it goes straight to the bottom left corner of the screen and I cannot move it.